# expr - managing strings

Tags: shell, regular-expression, string

I need to take text like this:

```
A234321=http://www.google..... a normal URL
```

And pull out only the URL, getting rid of the first part. I think I can use `expr` to do it, but I can't figure out the right way

The entire regex I can use is `http:[a-zA-Z0-9/_]+`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you're looking for this. See if it helps.

```
expr 'A234321=http://www.google&x=y' : '^[^=]*=\(.*\)'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!, it works like a charm!

What does it mean this part? '^[^=]*=

Thanks,

Marco

Comment: @Marco `^` means "at the beginning of the line". `[]` is a character class, so it can match a set of characters. The `^` inside it means "match all characters except these", so `[^=]` means "any character except =". `*` means "0 or more times". So the whole thing is "At the beginning of the line, match 0 or more characters that aren't =, followed by a single =", so it matches everything from the beginning of the line to the first = character

Answer (score 2):

You don't need expr for that. You can use the shell constructs `${VAR#PATTERN}` which expands to `$VAR` with the shortest prefix that matches the specified pattern stripped off, `${VAR##PATTERN}` which strips the longest prefix, and `${VAR%PATTERN}` and `${VAR%%PATTERN}` which strip suffixes.

```
text='A234321=http://www.example.com/wibble'
protocol=${text%%://*}
url=${protocol##*[!a-z]}://${text#*://}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text is always separated by an '=' character, the `cut` will give you the URL:

```
url=`echo $text | cut -f 2 -d"="`
```

Basically, here we are cutting the text field, delimited by `=` and extracting the 2nd field.